# Is there a way to dynamicly create @RabbitListner in Java RabbitMQ

Tags: java, annotations, rabbitmq

i've got a problem creating dynamic listner: @RabbiListner annotation doesn't provide a way to insert attributes which aren't constants. But in my project i'll get the name of exchange and queue only in dynamycs. For example:

```
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class AmqpReceiver {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessEngine camunda;

    private String exchnageName;

    private String queueName;

    public AmqpReceiver(ProcessEngine camunda, String exchnageName, String queueName) {
        this.camunda = camunda;
        this.exchnageName = exchnageName;
        this.queueName = queueName;
    }

   /**
    * Consumer for starting business process instance with required params
    */
    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
        value = @Queue(value = queueName, durable = "true"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = exchnageName, type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC, durable = "true"),
        key = "*"))
    @Transactional
    public void receiveQueue(Message<byte[]> message) {
        String payload = new String(message.getPayload());
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        }.getType();
        HashMap<String, Object> requestParams = new Gson().fromJson(payload, type);
        ProcessInstance processInstance = camunda.getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey("processName", requestParams);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this work? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is a way for create a listener dynamicly:

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("queueName");
    container.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    container.setMessageListener(new Consumer(container));
    container.start();
```